# vector of pointer

Tags: c++

I just wonder what's wrong with vector of pointer. some of my friend recommend me to use list instead of vector. will this cause a problem:

```
vector<Fruit*> basket;
basket.push_back(new Apple());
basket.push_back(new Orange());
vector<Fruit*> temp;
temp.push_back(basket[1]);
```

If I delete vector temp, do I destroy the basket[1] object too? if not, what's the problem with using vector of pointer?

Comment: `basket[1]` is just a pointer, and there's no problem destroying it. The problem with pointers in general is that you need to understand the difference between `basket[1]` and `*basket[1]`.

Comment: Q: What's wrong with vector of pointer.  A: Basically, nothing.  C++ purists might cringe in horror.  But it's perfectly legal and, IMHO, often perfectly appropriate.

Comment: @paulsm4 True, but often used sub-optimally. Introducing the need for a `delete` = sub-optimal

Comment: @paulsm4 Why would anyone cringe.  It's ubiquitious: just about any time you have to navigate from one object to more than one object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I delete vector temp, do I destroy the basket[1] object too?

**No**. First of all, you cannot *delete* `temp`; rather, it will get destroyed when going out of scope. And when this happens, the objects pointed by elements of the vector won't be  automatically `delete`d.

This is, however, not a specific problem of `vector`: using `list` will not save you from this issue. The problem is rather with *raw pointers*. If you want the pointed objects to be automatically deallocated when the the lifetime of the last pointer which points to it ends, you should use smart pointers.

Depending on the ownership policy that your application needs, you might choose between `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr`. The caveat with `shared_ptr` is that referencing cycles shall be avoided, to prevent mutually referencing objects from keeping each other alive. You may want to check `weak_ptr` in this respect.

Finally, unless you have a good reason for *not* using `vector`, `vector` should be the default choice for a container. From Paragraph 23.2.3/2 of the C++11 Standard:

> The sequence containers offer the programmer different complexity trade-offs and should be used accordingly. **`vector` or `array` is the type of sequence container that should be used by default**. `list` or `forward_list` should be used when there are frequent insertions and deletions from the middle of the sequence. `deque` is the data structure of choice when most insertions and deletions take place at the beginning or at the end of the sequence.

Answer (score 3):

If either of the vectors, `basket` or `temp`, are destroyed none of the `Fruit`s are destroyed. Anything that is dynamically allocated with `new` must be `delete`d. When the vectors go out of scope, they do not `delete` the objects that are pointed to by their elements. If you `delete` an object through one vector that is pointed to in the other vector, both point at the now `delete`d object.

Since your vectors have automatic storage duration, you definitely *must not* do `delete basket;` or `delete temp;`.

It's not recommended to use raw pointers in general, especially with dynamically allocated storage that you may forget to `delete`. In this case, however, you *do* need polymorphic behaviour, which is provided by pointers. You should use a *smart pointer* to avoid the problems with raw pointers. Try a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Fruit>>`.

Comment: With the added caveat that if you *don't* create an object with "new", then you *must not* try to "delete" that object :)

Comment: Vectors of pointers are probably most often used for navigation.  In such cases, raw pointers _are_ the recommended solution; none of the smart pointers I've seen can handle navigation correctly.

Comment: @JamesKanze Maybe the [worlds dumbest smart pointer](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3514.pdf) would be useful in that case.

Comment: Note that in his example, `std::unique_ptr` would have very surprising (and probably unwanted) side effects, leaving an invalid pointer in `basket[1]`.

Comment: @sftrabbit The `non_owning_ptr` sounds like a good idea---it is worth documenting that a particular pointer _is_ for navigation.  In one application, I also used `managed_ptr`, which registered itself as an observer with the pointed to object, and was set to null in the destructor of that object.  It turned out to be less useful than I thought, because the nulled pointer still hung around in maps, vectors, etc., so I still needed an observer at a higher level to clean them up.

Comment: @sftrabbit `shared_ptr` isn't necessarily any better: if the objects also contain `shared_ptr` to other objects, you risk cycles, and if the object has a lifetime defined by the program logic (i.e. it should be deletes in response to an external event), then `shared_ptr` will cause even more problems.  There are definite cases where `shared_ptr` is appropriate, but it shouldn't be used without careful thought beforehand.